# Can a set be a subring of a ring with different operation?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

While checking many sites about subrings and how to prove a subset of a ring $R$ is also a subring of it, I saw many sites asking if a set is a subring of a ring but even the operation in these two sets are different, and this is contradictory to the definition of a subring!

For example, I saw a question that asks if $\mathbb{Z_6}$ is a subring of $\mathbb{Z_{12}}$, and justifies that's not by showing that it's not closed under addition $mod$ $12$: $5+5= 10$ $mod$ $12$, but $10$ is not in $\mathbb{Z_6}$. I can't understand this way of disproving anymore, since $10$ in $\mathbb{Z_{12}}$ is different from $10$ in $\mathbb{Z_6}$ which's $4$ $mod$ $6$, we are talking about different operations!! ( addition $mod$ $12$ and addition $mod$ $6$ ), so this is clear that $\mathbb{Z_6}$ is not a subring of $\mathbb{Z_{12}}$ without the need of a proof! So why are many sites dealing the same way with such questions?!

I have another one:

Can we consider $\mathbb{Z_p}$ a $subset$ of $\mathbb{Z_q}$ if $p\leq q$??

I thought this is right because while deciding whether a set is a subset of another set, we don't look at their operations, but I was shocked that one site writes: $\mathbb{Z_{2}}$ is  $not$ $a$ $subset$ of $\mathbb{Z_{6}}$!

I feel like I have many new problems in abstract algebra, please help me to reorder my info !

Comment: so $\mathbb{Z_{6}}$ is a subring of $\mathbb{Z_{12}}$ and $\mathbb{Z_{2}}$ is a subring of $\mathbb{Z_{6}}$ regardless the different operations??

Comment: Oh I didn't take ring homomorphisms till now, can you illustarte in other ways?

Comment: @Nour You don't have to think of it as a monomorphism of $\Bbb Z/n \Bbb Z$ into $\Bbb Z/m \Bbb Z$ if you don't want to. Just look at the elements of $\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$ and $\Bbb Z/m \Bbb Z$, in the same way you would if you were trying to list sub**groups** of $\Bbb Z/m \Bbb Z$

Comment: @ÍgjøgnumMeg, aha, $\mathbb{Z_{12}}$  has 6 subgroups, none of them is $\mathbb{Z_{6}}$, so $\mathbb{Z_{6}}$ is not a subring of $\mathbb{Z_{12}}$. Right ?

Comment: @Nour I didn't really mean it like that, I was merely setting up an analogy; looking at elements is usually a lot less convenient than looking at the structure as a whole, but it's good to build up intuition when you're starting out. Regarding your comment, a ring **IS** an abelian group under addition, and also has some further multiplicative structure which is compatible with the addition operation. If you have a candidate for a subring, you certainly want it to also be a sub**group** of your ring when considered as an additive abelian group.

Comment: @Nour Also, $\Bbb Z/12 \Bbb Z$ does contain $\Bbb Z/6\Bbb Z$ as a subgroup; think of the set $\left\lbrace 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10\right\rbrace$ under addition modulo $12$.

Comment: @Famke What is your injective ring homomorphism from $\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$ to $\Bbb Z/4\Bbb Z$?

Comment: @ÍgjøgnumMeg so sorry, but I can't understand your last comment! How can $\mathbb{Z_{6}}$ be a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z_{12}}$? I'm really confused!

Comment: @Nour Well, more specifically, there is a subgroup of $\Bbb Z/12 \Bbb Z$ that is isomorphic to $\Bbb Z/ 6 \Bbb Z$.

Comment: @ÍgjøgnumMeg ok got this point, but I still have only one question: is $\mathbb{Z_{6}}$ not a subring of $\mathbb{Z_{12}}$ because of the different operations? i.e. $\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$ contains equivalence classes modulo $6$, while $\mathbb{Z}/12\mathbb{Z}$ contains equivalence classes modulo $12$, so even the $0$ additive inverse is different in both.

Comment: @Lord Shark the Unknown ; Yes you are right; there is no ring-homomorphism from $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$; there is only a group-homomorphism. Thank you for your point my dear Lord Shark the Unknown.

Answer (score 1):

Being a subring *requires* sharing the operations.

Any (nonempty) subset $S$ of a given ring $R$ can be considered as a ring on its own with different operations. Just use the fact that there is a ring $A$ with the same cardinality of $S$ and transfer the operations on $S$.

What would be the usefulness of this? None. Changing the bijection between $A$ and $S$ would change the ring structure, but there will be no connection whatsoever with the operations in $R$, in general.

About $\mathbb{Z}_6$ being a subset of $\mathbb{Z}_{12}$, the situation is similar. You *can* define a map $\mathbb{Z}_6\to\mathbb{Z}_{12}$ by decreeing that $[x]_6$ is mapped to the residue class modulo 12 that contains the least nonnegative element in $[x]_6$; so
\begin{align}
[0]_6&\mapsto[0]_{12} & [1]_6&\mapsto[1]_{12} & [2]_6&\mapsto[2]_{12} \\
[3]_6&\mapsto[3]_{12} & [4]_6&\mapsto[4]_{12} & [5]_6&\mapsto[5]_{12}
\end{align}
but you could also decide to map $[x]_6$ to the residue class modulo $12$ of the greatest negative element in $[x]_6$, so
\begin{align}
[0]_6&\mapsto[-6]_{12}=[6]_{12} & [1]_6&\mapsto[-5]_{12}=[7]_{12} &
[2]_6&\mapsto[-4]_{12}=[8]_{12} \\
[3]_6&\mapsto[-3]_{12}=[9]_{12} & [4]_6&\mapsto[-2]_{12}=[10]_{12} &
[5]_6&\mapsto[-1]_{12}=[11]_{12}
\end{align}
Both maps are injective, but they're quite different from each other. Which one is “right”? Neither: both depend on a somewhat arbitrary choice of an element in $[x]_6$.

A good question might be: is there an injective map $f\colon\mathbb{Z}_6\to\mathbb{Z}_{12}$ such that the image is a subring? Well, this depends on what you mean by subring. If you require that subrings also share the identity with the overring, then the answer is no: $\mathbb{Z}_{12}$ has no proper subring in this sense.

So let's not bother with the identity. Then, yes: $\mathbb{Z}_{12}$ has a unique additive subgroup of order $6$, namely $2\mathbb{Z}_{12}$, which happens to be an ideal of $\mathbb{Z}_{12}$ (hence a subring, under the stated convention). More precisely, the map
$$
[x]_{6}\mapsto [2x]_{12}
$$
is actually a *ring homomorphism* (when not requiring the identity is mapped on the identity). The map is well defined: indeed, if $x\equiv y\pmod{6}$, then $2x\equiv 2y\pmod{12}$.